# Schema pg_dump failed due to a Lock on a table

Tags: postgresql, locking, restore

I'm running backup restore on a schema every day and get this every now and then:

> pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR: relation not found (OID
> 86157003) DETAIL: This can be validly caused by a concurrent delete
> operation on this object. pg_dump: The command was: LOCK TABLE
> myschema.products IN ACCESS SHARE MODE

How can this be avoided? It seems the table was being used at the time, or someone was running something against the table. can I just kill all connections to the DB before restoring or is there another alternative?

As far as I understand, pg_dump could run even if users are doing something with the table but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks,

Comment: It would help to know what version of pg_dump you are using and what version of Postgres you are dumping? Also the actual dump command you where using?

Answer (score 1):

It is somewhat buried but the answer lies here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

"
-j njobs

...

To detect this conflict, the pg_dump worker process requests another shared lock using the NOWAIT option. If the worker process is not granted this shared lock, somebody else must have requested an exclusive lock in the meantime and there is no way to continue with the dump, so pg_dump has no choice but to abort the dump.
"

Which is borne out by the this in the error message:

"LOCK TABLE myschema.products IN ACCESS SHARE MODE"

`ACCESS SHARE` will cooperate with all other locks modes except `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE`. `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` is used by `DROP TABLE`, `TRUNCATE`, `REINDEX`, etc. See here [Locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) for more information. So you need to do the dump during a time where the operations listed for `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` are known to not happen or by blocking/dropping connections.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody dropped a table between the time `pg_dump` took an inventory of the tables and the time it tries to dump the table.

This can happen if your application is in the habit of dropping tables all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your main question, but a caution regarding:

> As far as I understand, pg_dump could run even if users are doing something with the table but it doesn't seem to be the case.

It assumes that the application performs every action in a single transaction. I have known of applications which accomplish some tasks using more than one.

I don't know exactly what the tasks were or if it was unavoidable that they use multiple transactions, but dumps could only be trusted when the application was idle or, better yet, when the service was stopped.

For the function that those applications performed, it wasn't a big deal to work around down times or stop services.

I don't know how you'd determine this behaviour without being told by the developers. Just something to consider.